# SSRS - Report doesn't loads via Report Builder, while it does via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

this is my first question here.
I struggled days and days trying to find a solution everywhere with no success.

Basically I have a standard stored procedure pulling out a report dataset in a few seconds (5-6 seconds).
It aggregates (GROUPING BY and SUMMING) 23000 rows.
Indeed, my final dataset comes out with 4 rows and 33 columns executing, as said, in 5-6 seconds.

Unfortunately, while trying to load it via ReportBuilder, it loads endlessly (querying SQL Server, the StoredProcedure remains stuck in a RUNNING status forever).
Everything on ReportBuilder (DB Accesses, Dataset, Parameters, Matrix....) is right configured: I was indeed able to load it until I added a few additional (4) fields.

The SQL dataset is basically something like:

```
PARAMETERS DECLARATION

SELECT
  FIELDS
FROM
(SELECT
  FIELD A
  SUMS
 FROM
 TABLE
  JOIN TABLES
 WHERE
  PARAMETERS MATCHING
 GROUP BY A
) AS B
ORDER BY FIELD
```

An "external layer" SELECT was needed to make some calculations on some FIELDS, also in some cases using some PARAMETERS.

That's it.

I use to work with huge datasets, sometimes pulling out 30,000 rows with 110 fields, but if something loads via SQL it also does always via ReportBuilder: this is the very first time it behaves in this different way. 
So I'm asking if there are some strange SSRS/ReportBuilder limitations I never faced in my experience.

Any help would be really really appreciated!

Thanks in advance to everyone who'll spend time :)

Comment: Are the parameters you pass to the sp from the Report? I  that case they might be wrong or null